# Php mysql sum with join group by date

Tags: php, mysql

hello I need help to resolve my code here.

I tried the following query;

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(buy.date, '%Y-%m-%d') date 
     , SUM(buy.total) sumbuy 
     , SUM(sell.total) sumsell  
  FROM buy  
  JOIN sell  
    ON DATE_FORMAT(buy.date, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(sell.date,'%Y-%m-%d') 
 WHERE buy.trans = 'credit' 
   AND sell.trans= 'debit'  
 GROUP 
    BY DATE_FORMAT(buy.date, '%d')
```

the result is:

```
   date        sumbuy       sumsell
 ------------------------------------
 2017-02-01    1560000      8080000
```

what I expected is:

```
        date        sumbuy       sumsell
     ------------------------------------
     2017-02-01     390000       2020000
```

here for the complete table

*buy*

```
total           trans            date
-----------------------------------------------
140000         credit       2017-02-01 04:31:00
50000          credit       2017-02-01 04:32:00
190000         debit        2017-02-01 04:33:00
50000          credit       2017-02-01 04:34:00
150000         credit       2017-02-01 04:35:00
```

*sell*

```
    total         trans         date
   ------------------------------------------
   120000         debit    2017-02-01 04:31:00
   300000         debit    2017-02-01 04:32:00
   800000         debit    2017-02-01 04:33:00
   800000         debit    2017-02-01 04:35:00
```

please anyone help me resolve this.

Comment: It seems confusing to me to have a buy table and sell table AND a trans column that can be both debit and credit. See, I'm confused. Why not just have one table?

Comment: I required the both table for my project, that is for the example so I make it so simple, :D

Comment: why you required two tables? you can just defer the transaction by type.

Comment: because both table have debit and credit transaction, and no way to make it to be one table

Comment: why sumbuy = 390000?

Comment: 140000 + 50000+ 50000 + 150000 = 390000

Comment: not sure why the requirement, but I have seen accountants that program or create table like that (a credit table and a debit table), although technically there's no need for that. As others already pointed out, you could create 1 table for both with a type (credit  or debit) and make 2 views so it looks like two tables

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query
. Don't include irrelevant columns, but DO include the PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: your where clause isn't doing anything, you're selecting both types of transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'and no way to make it to be one table' - this assertion is frankly ridiculous.

Anyway...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS buy;

CREATE TABLE buy
(total INT NOT NULL
,trans enum('credit','debit')
,date DATETIME NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO buy VALUES
(140000,'credit','2017-02-01 04:31:00'),
( 50000,'credit','2017-02-01 04:32:00'),
(190000,'debit' ,'2017-02-01 04:33:00'),
( 50000,'credit','2017-02-01 04:34:00'),
(150000,'credit','2017-02-01 04:35:00');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sell;

CREATE TABLE sell
(total INT NOT NULL
,trans enum('credit','debit')
,date DATETIME NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO sell VALUES
(120000,'debit','2017-02-01 04:31:00'),
(300000,'debit','2017-02-01 04:32:00'),
(800000,'debit','2017-02-01 04:33:00'),
(800000,'debit','2017-02-01 04:35:00');

SELECT DATE(date) date 
     , SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'buy' AND trans = 'credit' THEN total END) sumbuy
     , SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'sell' AND trans = 'debit' THEN total END) sumsell 
  FROM
     ( SELECT * 
            ,'buy' type 
         FROM buy
        UNION 
          ALL
       SELECT *
            ,'sell' 
         FROM sell
     ) x
 GROUP 
    BY DATE(date);
+------------+--------+---------+
| date       | sumbuy | sumsell |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 2017-02-01 | 390000 | 2020000 |
+------------+--------+---------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

[SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/003ed1/12/0)

Comment: and @strawberry beat me again, still struggling to find a better solution, maybe I need to change my nick to [tag:apple]?

Comment: well, very helpful answers. thank you very much Strawberry.

Comment: @strawberry, there a only few records in this case, but in case of many records, which solution would work faster?

Comment: @davejal I suspect that there's not a lot in it - but I wouldn't know without testing.

Answer (score 0):

Already a solution to your question but maybe this one could help anyone else in another situation

```
select date, sum(sumbuy) as totalbuy, sum(sumsell) as totalsell from (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(buy.date, '%Y-%m-%d') date 
     , SUM(case when trans = 'credit' then total else 0 end) as sumbuy
     , SUM(case when trans = 'debit' then total else 0 end) as sumsell 
  FROM buy 
  GROUP 
    BY DATE_FORMAT(buy.date, '%d')
union 
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(sell.date, '%Y-%m-%d') date 
     , SUM(case when trans = 'credit' then total else 0 end) as sumbuy
     , SUM(case when trans = 'debit' then total else 0 end) as sumsell 
  FROM sell 
  GROUP 
    BY DATE_FORMAT(sell.date, '%d')) a
    group by date
```

I noticed you got **2020000** for sumsell, shouldn't be **2210000** or do you explicitly don't want the debit transaction from the buy table?

In case you only want the debits from the sell table and only the credits from the buy table you could rewrite your query like this:

```
select date, sum(sumbuy) as totalbuy, sum(sumsell) as totalsell from (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(buy.date, '%Y-%m-%d') date 
 , SUM(case when trans = 'credit' then total else 0 end) as sumbuy
 , SUM(case when trans = 'debit' then total else 0 end) as sumsell 
  FROM buy 
 where trans = 'credit'
GROUP 
BY DATE_FORMAT(buy.date, '%d')
union 
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(sell.date, '%Y-%m-%d') date 
 , SUM(case when trans = 'credit' then total else 0 end) as sumbuy
 , SUM(case when trans = 'debit' then total else 0 end) as sumsell 
FROM sell 
where trans = 'debit'
GROUP 
BY DATE_FORMAT(sell.date, '%d')) a
group by date
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/003ed1/11/0)